# Is it safe to pass variable that depends on a context to AsyncTask

Tags: android, asynchronous, weak-references

I have variable created in `onCreate()` like this:
`DataClient dataClient = Wearable.getDataClient(this)`

Then I pass this variable to my **static AsyncTask** in constructor. I use it in `doInBackground()`. As I understand - **that's a leak** (using context-depending variable in async task blocks GC from cleaning activity until task is finished).

**Possible solution** is to use weak reference to `dataClient`.
**The problem with weak reference** is that I heard you must not dereference it in `doInBackground()`, only in `onPostExecute()`, but I need it in `doInBackground()`.

What can I do?

Comment: cancel your asynctask in onpause so you won't leak context